# docker-compose No such command: convert error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/#run-a-compose-application) on AWS ECS integration that mentions the Docker command `docker compose convert` that is supposed to generate a AWS CloudFormation template.

However, when I run this command, it doesn't appear to exist.

```
$ docker-compose convert
No such command: convert
#...

$ docker compose convert
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

$ docker context create ecs myecscontext
"docker context create" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker context create --help'.

Usage:  docker context create [OPTIONS] CONTEXT

Create a context
```

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        4484c46
 Built:             Thu Oct 15 18:34:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.12
  Git commit:       77e06fd
  Built:            Mon Jun  8 20:24:59 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 12
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 149
 Server Version: 19.03.11
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: 
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.8.0-29-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 16
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 16
 Total Memory: 7.202GiB
 Name: HongLee
 ID: GZ5R:KQDD:JHOJ:KCUF:73AE:N3NY:MWXS:ABQ2:2EVY:4ABJ:H375:J64V
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `docker compose convert` use docker new compose command. If not working can you switch on experimental features?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I tried that but I get `docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.` so maybe I have something disabled... ???

Comment: take a look at [this](https://techsparx.com/software-development/docker/docker-ecs/first-look/docker-compose.html)

Comment: @Nate What OS are you running on? Docker for Windows/Mac is slightly different than Linux.

Comment: Is Docker Desktop version >= 2.3.0.5

Comment: @JeffreyMixon I'm running on Ubuntu latest.

Comment: I updated my question with details of `docker version` and `docker info`

Answer (score 3):

To get the ECS integration, you need to be using an ECS docker context. First, enable the [experimental flag](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md) in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```json
// /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "experimental": true
}
```

Then create the context:

```
docker context create ecs myecscontext
docker context use myecscontext
```

```
$ docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                                       ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock   [redacted] (default)   swarm
myecscontext *      ecs
```

Now run `convert`:

```
$ docker compose convert
WARN[0000] services.build: unsupported attribute        
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  AdminwebService:
    DependsOn:
    - AdminwebTCP80Listener
    Properties:
      Cluster:
...
```

Comment: When I run this, I get `"docker context create" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Comment: @Nate it looks like your Docker server engine is slightly behind your CLI client (`19.03.11` vs `19.03.13`). Mine are both `19.03.13`. `dpkg -l | grep docker-ce` ? Can you upgrade your docker server package?

Comment: I also have [experimental options](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md) enabled, but it shouldn't apply in this case

Comment: @Nate Actually, experimental mode is required it seems. I updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think experimental mode is still required. It does *not* help avoid the error on Linux, which OP is using. See my answer. Unlike with Docker for Desktop on Windows and Mac, the even latest 20.10.6 docker binary does not support the compose subcommand. See https://github.com/docker/compose-cli to download and configure.

Answer (score 2):

You're running on Ubuntu. The `/usr/bin/docker` installed (even with latest docker-ce 20.10.6) does **not** enable the `docker compose` subcommand. It *is* enabled by default on Docker for Desktop Windows or Mac.

See the **Linux** installation instructions at https://github.com/docker/compose-cli to download and configure so that `docker compose` works.

There's a `curl|bash` script for Ubuntu or just download the latest release, put that `docker` executable into a `PATH` directory before `/usr/bin/` and make sure the original `docker` is available as `com.docker.cli` e.g. `ln -s /usr/bin/docker ~/bin/com.docker.cli`.